# Excluding records using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to get exclude the email_id that has any name and end with either @abcd.in or @abcd.live and only include the email's having mobile numbers, but not sure if this is the correct regex I'm using, can you help?

the statement I'm using to filter is below

```
(NOT(lower(`table`.`user_email`) like '[a-z].*@Abcd.in$'|'[a-z].*@Abcd.live$')
```

Comment: `and only include the email's having mobile numbers` ... can you include some examples of valid emails?

Comment: 1234567890@Abcd.in, 
0987654321@Abcd.live,
abkljdva@gmail.com,
@hotmail.com etc these can be included and also alpha numeric like absdc12342@gmail/Hotmail etc 
but the sanchay@Abcd.in / sanchay@Abcd.live  shouldn't be included

Comment: `'0987654321.sanchay@Abcd.live'` should be ... `'0987654321.s@Abcd.live'` should be ...

Comment: `like` does not support regex. You must have meant `RLIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE`. What is MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina Yes that should get included in the selection

Comment: First example contains a name. In the question you tell that "to get exclude the email_id that has any name" - i.e. it must be excluded... but now you tell that it should be included. Clarify your needs.

Comment: @akina
 if the email id ends with __@ABCD.IN or __@ABCD.LIVE and start with numbers and has alphabets i.e if it is an alphanumeric email like '1233578@ABCD.in or sanchay1234@ABCD.in  or 1234567@ABCD.live or sanchay1234@ABCD.live then it
can be included that ends with ABCD.in or ABCD.live or any other email service provider, but if there is a name or just alphabets like Sanchay@ABCD.in or Sanchay@Abcd.live these should get excluded the one that has __@ABCD.in or __@ABCD.live I hope this explanation will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do filtering based on a regular expression, you should be using `REGEXP` or `REGEXP_LIKE` (both are synonyms).  Assuming you just want to exclude the two domains mentioned, you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE email NOT REGEXP '[a-z]+@Abcd\.(in|live)$';
```

Assuming you wanted to enhance the above by also whitelisting certain email patterns, you could make another call to `REGEXP`.

Comment: Thanks Tim Just wanted to understand will also exclude the emails if they have numbers and ends with _@Abcd.in or _@Abcd.live because I only want to exclude the ones like sanchay@abcd.in or tim@abcd.in/live not the ones that have 23456@abcd.in/23456@abcd.live

Comment: @SanchayBhargava OK...I updated my question so that now it would only exclude e.g. `sanchay@abcd.in` or `tim@abcd.live`, but not an email with the blacklisted domain but a numerical address.

Comment: Note that `LOWER()` was removed on the presumption that you are using a "case insensitive" collation for the column.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably do something like this:

```
SELECT *
 FROM mytable
  WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email,'@',-1) IN ('Abcd.live','Abcd.in')
   AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email,'@',1) REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to separate the email name and domain by using `@` as delimiter. The first condition is simply just filtering the domain with `IN` so other than the ones being defined, it will be omitted. Then the second condition is using `REGEXP` to check if numerical values are present in the email name.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c026cda0f17fe3192a67672fdd29fb5)